# replace multiple cell value from a group of strings

Tags: excel

Hi I want to replace multiple values in one for example :

sunny   91878656    rere

vicky   91864567    gfgf

honey   91941561    ytyt

monika  98887888    hjhj

NOw if I want to replace the following two values together with space:

```
91941561    
98887888
```

How can I do it ?

I dont want to do simple find and replace as this is just an exmaple I have a list of over 12000 records and the numbers which needs to be replaced are more than 900
the reason i want to replace is they are not valid anymore.

also is it possible to remove whole record like if 91941561 is found whole of the record should be deleted or replaced with space like:

honey   91941561    ytyt
monika  98887888    hjhj

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Regular expression. Below is a sample code

```
Sub test()

    Dim str_demo As String
    str_demo = "monika 98887888 hjhj"
    MsgBox getString(str_demo)


End Sub

Function getString(ByVal str As String) As String
    Dim objRegEx As Object
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegEx.Global = True

    objRegEx.Pattern = "[a-zA-Z]"

    Set allMatches = objRegEx.Execute(str)

    For i = 0 To allMatches.Count - 1
        result = result & allMatches.Item(i)
    Next

    getString = result
End Function
```